# Clustering incosistencys by time difference in a timeseries df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
df
Out[94]: 
                          nr  aenvm  aenhm  ...  naenhs  naesvs  naeshs
date                                        ...                        
2019-11-16 08:44:24        1    388    776  ...     402     305     566
2019-11-16 08:44:25        2    383    767  ...     407     304     561
2019-11-16 08:44:26        3    378    762  ...     410     301     570
2019-11-16 08:44:27        4    376    766  ...     403     304     567
2019-11-16 08:44:28        5    374    773  ...     398     297     569
```

The data is inconsistent by `Events`.
Sometimes there are around 6 minutes of data (lets call it an `"event"`) and then for maybe some hours or some days no data. See i.e. the structure break in the timestamp:

```
df.iloc[1056:1065]
Out[95]: 
                       nr  aenvm  aenhm  aesvm  ...  naenvs  naenhs  naesvs  naeshs
date                                            ...                                
2019-11-17 05:18:49  1057    276    707    477  ...     244     136     247     525
2019-11-17 05:18:50  1058    268    703    470  ...     238     138     228     504
2019-11-17 05:56:45  1059    304    717    508  ...     295     157     282     519
2019-11-17 05:56:46  1060    304    715    507  ...     302     159     289     508
```

All I want to do is to `"index"` or `"categories"` those events. That the rows between two structural breaks are combined under one number [1, 2, 3, ...] in a new column.

My Goal is to creat a new column like "nr" that seperates the "events".

```
Out[95]: 
                       nr  aenvm  aenhm  aesvm  ...  naenvs  naenhs  naesvs  naeshs
date                                            ...                                
2019-11-17 05:18:49  1    276    707    477  ...     244     136     247     525
2019-11-17 05:18:50  1    268    703    470  ...     238     138     228     504
2019-11-17 05:56:45  2    304    717    508  ...     295     157     282     519
2019-11-17 05:56:46  2    304    715    507  ...     302     159     289     508
```

To be honest I am a complete python newbie, I tried some classification with the timestamp `datetime64` and `.asfreq` but with zero to nothing success...
I would be very thankfully for a good advice! :)

Comment: please explain what you mean with "structural event".
Further please provide us with a rdy to use dataframe of example data, so we can provide you with a solution.
Best practice: Input dataframe with a small example, expected output, description what you need.
This way it would be much easier for us to help you, so more people will try :)

Comment: @Semmel, thanks for the feedback. Data is only recorded at certain times for around 5 to 6 minutes, wich is an "event". That means that the timestamp is inconsistent (see 2nd code example). Every time Data is newly recorded, that means there is a differences in the timestamp to the upper row, i want to raise an index in a new row. so later i can filter by those number and not single rows.

Comment: i added my goal in the post, but i cant get a example dataframe running because i am unable to simulate a disrupted timeseries in a dataframe :( maybe someone has an idea?